# How to skip relationships hash from serialized object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

How can I skip relationships hash from a serialized object (gem Netflix/fast_jsonapi)?

```
{
  "data": {
    "id": "3",
    "type": "movie",
    "attributes": {
      "name": "test movie",
      "year": null
    },
    "relationships": {
      "actors": {
        "data": [
          {
            "id": "1",
            "type": "actor"
          },
          {
            "id": "2",
            "type": "actor"
          }
        ]
      },
      "owner": {
        "data": {
          "id": "3",
          "type": "user"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: post your serializer class file

Comment: there is a definition of [https://github.com/Netflix/fast_jsonapi#serializer-definition]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use rails except method to remove an attribute from hash in your case you can      use

```
 data_hash = {"data": {"id": "3","type": "movie","attributes": {"name": "test movie","year":''},"relationships": {"actors": {"data": [{"id": "1","type": "actor"},{"id": "2","type": "actor"}]},"owner": {"data": {"id": "3","type": "user"}}}}}
 data_hash[:data].except!(:relationships)
```

You get output as below

```
{:id=>"3", :type=>"movie", :attributes=>{:name=>"test movie", :year=>""}}
```

And `data_hash` will be

```
{:data=>{:id=>"3", :type=>"movie", :attributes=>{:name=>"test movie", :year=>""}}}
```